# RSS file isn't XML

Tags: rss

OK, so here's an interesting one...

I'm writing a simple file analyser, which tries to recognise different sorts of files. I've been given a whole bunch of example files to test with.

I have no idea what "RSS" is, but everything I can find out about it claims it's XML-based. However, I've got a huge stack of `*.rss` files, and they look nothing like XML to me:

```
X-MS-FeedTitle: Microsoft At Work
From: "Microsoft at Work"
Subject: Keep yourself organized with Microsoft Outlook Tasks
Date: Mon, 27 Jun 2011 00:00:00 -0700
Message-ID: 00000026
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
    charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
X-MS-ItemUrl: http://www.microsoft.com/atwork/productivity/streamline.aspx?WT.rss_f=At Work RSS&WT.rss_a=Keep yourself organized with Microsoft Outlook Tasks&WT.rss_ev=a
X-MimeOLE: Produced By Microsoft MimeOLE V14.0.8117.416

77u/PEhUTUw+PEhFQUQ+PE1FVEEgaHR0cC1lcXVpdj1Db250ZW50LVR5cGUgY29udGVudD0idGV4
dC9odG1sOyBjaGFyc2V0PXV0Zi04Ij48U1RZTEU+Qk9EWSB7Zm9udC1mYW1pbHk6IEFyaWFsO2Zv
bnQtc2l6ZTogMTBwdDt9PC9TVFlMRT48L0hFQUQ+PEJPRFk+PGJyPlRoZXNlIHNpeCBNaWNyb3Nv
ZnQgT3V0bG9vayBUYXNrcyB0aXBzIHdpbGwgaGVscCB5b3Ugc3RheSBvbmUgc3RlcCBhaGVhZCBv
ZiB0aGUgY29tcGV0aXRpb24uPC9CT0RZPjwvSFRNTD4=
```

This isn't XML. It looks more like some kind of protocol headers, followed by a base64-encoded payload.

What *is* this stuff? It looks nothing like what I was expecting...

**Edit:** Below is the result of decoding the base64 block:

```
<HTML><HEAD><META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><STYLE>BODY {font-family: Arial;font-size: 10pt;}</STYLE></HEAD><BODY><br>These six Microsoft Outlook Tasks tips will help you stay one step ahead of the competition.</BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: Have you tried to base64 decode the body (anything after the double newline)?

Comment: @JulienGenestoux Now things get even more fun... If I decode the data, I get HTML. Not RSS. (Specifically, a HTML page with a `HEAD` but no `BODY`. No DocType either...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those aren't actual RSS feeds. They're the internal local copies of RSS data created by Windows Live Mail ([example here](http://www.vistax64.com/live-mail/129067-weird-spacing-rss-feeds.html)) when you read RSS feeds through it.